# Convert normal String to Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting this String as **input**

```
"countries" : "[[england, australia], [UAE, China], [UAE]]"
```

**Requirement**

I thought that, I need to transform this String into

```
{"countries": [["england", "australia"], ["UAE", "China"], ["UAE"]]}
```

Then I can convert **it to **Object** in js using json.parse() method.**

I tried various things but none seem to work.

**I Tried**

1. JSON.stringify
2. JSON.parse
3. eval

I have done this in Java but in **Javascript** not able to do so.
I am new to js, as in java I can easily do this JSONObject.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks !!

Comment: Suggestion: change your source to produce valid JSON instead of this random string.

Comment: If you have ```[["england", "australia"], ["UAE", "China"], ["UAE"]]```, what is the concern?

Comment: So Java Somehow is able to convert invalid JSON into JSON?

Comment: What produces `"countries" : "[[england, australia], [UAE, China], [UAE]]"`? Is there a reason you can not alter whatever is outputting that invalid JSON? You can write a parser that will do what you want, but the real solution is fix the thing that is broken, not to add a bandaid that can fail in other places.

Answer (score 0):

This requires multiple steps:

Wrap the input in curly braces and do a `JSON.parse`:

```
const input = "\"countries\" : \"[[england, australia], [UAE, China], [UAE]]\""
const result = JSON.parse("{" + input + "}")
```

That gives you an object like:

```
{
    "countries": "[[england, australia], [UAE, China], [UAE]]"
}
```

Then wrap the inner strings with double quotes and parse it again:

```
const inner = result.countries
result.countries = JSON.parse(inner.replaceAll(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, '"$1"'))
```

That gives you `result`:

```
{
  "countries": [
    [
      "england",
      "australia"
    ],
    [
      "UAE",
      "China"
    ],
    [
      "UAE"
    ]
  ]
}
```